# How do I send the SimpleCart total to the Paypal site/terminal

Tags: javascript, html, paypal, simplecart

I'm setting up a simple eCommerce site with SimpleCart(js) and using the Paypal payment terminal to process all payments.

How do I send the final total to the Paypal terminal?

This is what it looks like
[image]

When I click "Buy Now" it sends me to the Paypal terminal. But the total on the left still says $0.00

[image]

How do I send the "Final Total" ($107.99) to the Paypal site?

Comment: http://simplecartjs.org/documentation/paypal

Comment: @T.Shah Thanks but that doesn't help at all. It still doesn't send the total or quantity to the Paypal site.